# Can I invoke input from main method into another method in the class

Tags: java

I need to use information gathered from my main method in a different method within the same class. Is that possible? If so, how do I go about doing so? Basically I have to gather the info in main method and implement it in the other. Help!

If I gain information say:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class MyClass
{


 public static double main (String[] args)

 {

  double x, y, z;
  Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

  System.out.print ("Please enter x value: ");
  x= scan.nextDouble();

  System.out.print ("Please enter y value: ");
  y= scan.nextDouble();

  System.out.print ("Please enter z value: ");
  z= scan.nextDouble();

 }

public static void OtherMethod()
 {
  int a=0;
  while(x<y)
  {
  a++;
  double b=x* (z/100);
  x+=b;
  }
   System.out.println("After " + a + " time at " + z+ "%, you will have " + "$" + x);
 }
}
```

Comment: Yes, it's possible in many many ways. You can pass the variables as arguments to the method, or make them class-level static variables. Google it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.   If you change the first line of `OtherMethod` to

```
public static void OtherMethod(double x, double y, double z)
```

then you can call it from `main` with

```
OtherMethod(x, y, z);
```

which makes the `x, y, z` defined in `OtherMethod` equal to the `x, y, z` defined in `main`, for the purposes of the one method call.

**Gratuitous advice**

For the record, there are a few bad programming practices in your code snippet.  It's OK for now, since you're a beginner, but don't make a habit of any of them.

- Single letter variable names.  It's not obvious to someone working on this code that `x` is an amount of money, `y` is your savings target, `z` is the interest rate, and so on.  You should use full words or even multiple words for your variables.  Like `savingsTarget` and `interestRate`.
- Inconsistent spacing and indentation make code hard to read.
- Most people prefer not to put the `{` character on a line by itself.  Put it at the end of the previous line instead.
- You've used floating point types for money.  Don't ever store an amount of money in a `double` or a `float` variable.  These aren't designed for accurate mathematics with decimals.  Learn to use the `BigDecimal` class instead.
- Having static methods instead of creating objects is often indicative of poor design.  It also makes big programs much more difficult to test, if there are many static methods.
- Method names should begin with a lower case letter.  It makes your code a little easier to follow.

Just a few things to think about for your future programming efforts.

Comment: How do I then print the last line "System.out.println("After " + a + " time at " + z+ "%, you will have " + "$" + x);" All it gives me in return is the main method without any result. How do I show the calculations?

Comment: Exactly as you're doing it now.  Are you getting some kind of error?  It should be fine to print these from `OtherMethod()`.

Comment: yes it only prints what i ask aka "input value for x,y,z" then it ends the operation

Comment: Did you write `OtherMethod(x, y, z);` in your `main` method, after the lines to do the input?

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you are asking how to pass arguments to a function.

Try writing:

```
public static void OtherMethod(double x, double y, double z)
```

Inside Main:

```
OtherMethod(x,y,z)
```

Answer (score 0):

declare `double x, y, z;` as class level static attibutes -

```
private static double x;
private static double y;
private static double z;
```

Inside your main method then you can call `OtherMethod();`

Comment: -1 because (a) `OtherMethod` is static and you don't need to create a new instance of `MyClass` to call it; (b) using globals to pass values from one method to another is very poor programming practice.